# Wrong error interpretation by Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a following error handling function:

```
handleError(error) {
    this.loading = false;
    console.log(error);
    let errorMessage;
    if (error.error && error.error.detail) {
      errorMessage = error.error.detail;
    } else {
      errorMessage = error.status + ': ' + error.statusText;
    }

    this._snackbar.open("Error: " + errorMessage, 'OK');
  }
```

Here's how I'm using it:

```
this._apiService.stop(this.element.id).subscribe(element => {
  this.element = element;
}, error => {
  this.handleError(error);
});
```

It gets API error and tries to display its details (if provided), or just status text.

This code works perfectly fine in development environment (`ng serve`), but doesn't work in production (`ng build --prod`).

I've noticed a difference in how error detail is interpreted in production, see screenshots below:

Dev:
[image: dev]

Production:
[image: production]

You can see, that in development, `error.error` is an object with `detail` as parameter. In production, `error.error` is an object as a string.
Why is it happening? The error is served by Django Rest Framework if it matters.

Is there a parameter that defines how deep angular will resolve nested objects?

**EDIT**
I've noticed, that `ng build --prod` works fine on my local machine (Windows 10). The problem is on CentOS server.
Maybe it is some issue with npm settings?

Comment: is the back end service for dev and prod are same or different. may be this is what you get from service end

Comment: backend is the same, the only difference is that production is on the same host as backend, and dev has to connect via HTTP